# How can I make a value in one array the value in another array (VBA)?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, if-statement

I want to create a piece of code that lets me assign a value from a array to another array, which are of different lengths. This is what I have so far.

```
A(1) = 0
A(2) = 0
A(3) = 6
A(4) = 5
A(5) = 7

n = 0

For i = 1 To 5
If A(i) <> 0 Then
    n = n + 1
End If
Next i

ReDim B(1 To n) As Integer
For j = 1 To n
    For i = 1 To 5
        If A(i) <> 0 Then
            B(j) = A(i)
        End If
    Next i
Next j

MsgBox B(2)
```

At the moment this returns 7 whereas it should return 5, all values in B are 7. How can I get this code to run?

Comment: Your code seems to suggest you do not want to copy any 0 values. So if you had an array `(4, 2, 0, 8, 9)` you would want to have `B` with 4 elements only, like `(4, 2, 8, 9)`?

Comment: You code is a bit weird  :) I just don't understand what the final goal is. What you do : In the first loop you count the values that are not 0, it should result in `n=3`. After that you have 2 nested loops. The first one will run 3 times, the second one (nested) assigns to B array the values in A that are not 0. But the final result is always the same: it will assign to B the very last value of A that is not  0, thus `7`, and you end up with 7 everywhere. You seriously need to detail what you want exactly, with data of expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have nested loops should alarm you: this would be executed `n * 5` times, which cannot be correct.

Change the second part so it only uses one loop, like this:

```
ReDim B(1 To n) As Integer
j = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(A)
    If A(i) <> 0 Then
        B(j) = A(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Note also that using `UBound` instead of `5` makes your code more generic. Note also that this loop is very similar to the loop that calculates `n`. The only difference is that you assign to `B(j)`.

You could in fact combine it with the first loop, if you would re-dimension `B` twice, the second time with `Preserve`:

```
ReDim B(1 To UBound(A)) As Integer
n = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(A)
    If A(i) <> 0 Then
        n = n + 1
        B(n) = A(i)
    End If
Next i
' Shorten the array without losing data:
ReDim Preserve B(1 To n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to check B for the first empty array element and exit the loop so you do not continue to write.

```
Dim A() As Variant, B() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

A = Array(0, 0, 6, 5, 7)  '<~~ 0 to 4, not 1 to 5

n = 0
For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
    If A(i) <> 0 Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next i

ReDim B(1 To n) '<~~ 1 to 3

For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
    If A(i) <> 0 Then
        For j = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
            If IsEmpty(B(j)) Then
                B(j) = A(i) '<~~ assigned a value; exit loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

For j = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
    Debug.Print B(j)
Next j
```

Given that arrays can be either zero-based or one-based, I prefer to use the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx)  functions to define their scope.